# Meaning of ゴルフ場を国の土地にした

Tags: reading-comprehension

Regarding an American missile system in Korea:

> 韓国の国防省は２月２８日、ＴＨＡＡＤを置くために韓国の南にあるゴルフ場を**国の土地にした**と発表しました。
>   On the 28th of February South Korea's defence department announced that they had made a golf course, located in the south of the country, into ??? in order to install THAAD.

I'm not sure I understand ゴルフ場を国の土地にした, particularly the 国の土地 part. 
Literally I think this means "made the golf course into the country's land". Does this mean that the golf course is now owned by the government, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: In the US there is a legal term for it:  Eminent Domain.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eminent_domain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this 国の土地 means 国が所有する土地, or 国有地.

You have read the sentence correctly.